# Spring / Grails - reload bean with new properties

Tags: java, spring, grails

is there a way to change the properties of a spring bean (service) at runtime? I'm using grails for a small app, where the user is able to change some settings. These settings are written into a property file, which is in the ext config params at grails. So when I restart the application, the properties are read in and the bean is init with this changes, is there a way to reload my service without a full restart?

What I would like to achieve that the user can pass is settings to the service and everything is available at runtime.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595118/having-spring-bean-properties-refreshed-automatically-from-properties-file help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to redesign the way you're approaching this requirement. It is a huge code smell that your user can do things through the UI of the app that require a restart for them to take-effect.

Having said that, I think you can probably grab a hold of the [ApplicationContext object](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/14.%20Grails%20and%20Spring.html#14.1%20The%20Underpinnings%20of%20Grails), catch the event in the UI, and replace the instance of your service, since you should have access to the new configuration values in that context. But I would advise against it, it's a hacky solution that will come back to haunt you :)